# Split numeric string and perform function on them in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have cells of the form -

[image]

and I want to convert each cell into the formula -

= (first number)*10^(second number+2), where the first and second numbers are the ones that come before and after the comma. Whats the best way to do it?

Example -

=30*10^2   or

=9*10^8

Comment: do you want to do this in place with vba or in another cell with formula?  Either way it would be best if you showed what you tried and also tell us what version of Excel you are using.

Comment: @ScottCraner i am using Microsoft 365, and would love to do it into another cell with formula. Till now, I have just been doing this by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MID, LEFT and FIND to parse the string then do the math:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)*10^(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1))+2)
```

[image]

In Office 365 we can use LET for easier updating:

```
=LET(a,A1,b,FIND(",",a),LEFT(a,b-1)*10^(MID(a,b+1,LEN(a))+2))
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. thank you!